# How do I get Chromium and Firefox to detect my smart card reader?

Tags: firefox, chromium, smartcard

I have a SCR3310 Smart Card Reader that I am using with Ubuntu. I have verified that my smart card is connected using pcsc-tools, and that it can detect my smart card successfully. I also successfully created a NSS database for my smart card and I am using the openSC module. When I list the PKCS #11 Modules, I can see my openSC module and my smart card when it is inserted into the reader.

However, when I attempt to go to a smart card enabled website, I get "No certificates detected" errors. When I inspect the certificate store in my browser, there are no personal certificates available. Other guides indicate that I should be able to see my smart card credentials when I go to a smart card enabled website, as if I was using activclient on Windows-based browsers. The reason I am using Chromium for this is because Firefox will not even let me load any PKCS #11 modules, returning the error "Alert: Unable to add module" no matter what I do. I've tried moving the modules to different directories, and even changing ownership and permissions to no avail.

I've also followed the [Ubuntu CommonAccessCard Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CommonAccessCard) to a T, which outlines exactly what I've did above, and I am still unable to get the browsers to detect my smart card certificates.

Comment: I have the same problem with Ubuntu 20.04(MATE), Belkin usb card reader. I have an extra layer of bs, running Virtualbox ubuntu 20.04(MATE) VM... (you should probably state more about your system...always). I forgot what I did to solve the "unable to add module" problem, but it still didnt work after i fixed that. Out of fear of breaking my working system I am not going to test with it because i need it for work, but it works flawlessly with a CENTOS 7 VM. So you may want to look into whatever software Centos 7 uses on it. It comes w/ "Smart Card Manager" and there was little to add after that

Comment: This is caused by snap, see https://launchpad.net/bugs/1843392. You can increment the "affects N people" by clicking it.